# Replacing Git Repository with a new Local Copy

Tags: git

I have a QA environment that has a previous version of a converted hg repository stored in a git repository. For the purposes of testing, I need to re-run the conversion (using git-remote-hg) and push all the changes made over the past few weeks up to our QA git environment.

If all the history I need is in the local copy how do I replace the entire remote repository with my local one without deleting the remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force push.

To push a particular branch,

```
git push --force <remote> <branch>
```

To push all branches having the same name on both ends (**if `push.default` is set to `matching`**),

```
git push --force
```

This will overwrite the remote branch with your local branch.

Be careful on what you want to achieve before running the command. You will lose the commits.

As per the documentation,

> Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an
>   ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables the
>   check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it
>   with care.

**UPDATE**

After the force push is done for the `master` branch, you can push all the local branches that are not there in remote by,

```
git push <remote> --all
```

Comment: If on the remote end I only have remotes/origins/master but locally I have master plus several other branches, how do I get the additional branches to be pushed to the remote?

Comment: `git push origin --all` should do it.